# Composite residues with determinant denominators

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

I am looking for a good reference on composite residues of multi-variable contour integrals (something better and more explicit than Griffiths and Harris or Tsikh).  This means I want to evaluate $\oint \frac{d^nz}{p(z)}$ where $p(z)$ is a homogeneous degree $n$ polynomial in $n$ variables, and I want the residue at $z = 0$.

I understand that this is a difficult problem in general, but in my particular case one can regard the $z$ variables as entries in a matrix, and $p(z)$ is a product of various minor determinants of this matrix.  I know what the answer should be ahead of time, and I know that it's pretty, but I can't prove it, so I'd be interested in references where similar residues have been computed.

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in this area but perhaps ["Residue calculus and applications"](https://doi.org/10.2977/prims/1199403807) by M. Elkadi and A. Yger, and the references therein, as well as the ["residue form"](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Residue_form) entry on the Springer Encyclopedia of Mathematics, could help a bit.